# MongoDB::NetworkTimeout: Timed out while waiting for socket to become ready for reading

Tags: mongodb, perl

I have perl script to run mongo query.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl 
        use strict;
        use warnings;
        use MongoDB;
        use Data::Printer;
        use MongoDB::QueryResult;

        my $mc   = MongoDB->connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27012/test_db');
        my $coll = $mc->ns("test_db.collection1");

        my @permissibleCars =
         ("ABC","DEF","XYZ","MNO","PQR"); 
        my @pipeline = (
            {
                '$match' => {
                    "Contract"        => { '$in' => \@permissibleCars },
                    "Class" => "Right"
                    }
            },
            { '$group' => { _id => '$Contract', count => { '$sum' => 9 } } }
        );

        my $res = $coll->aggregate( \@pipeline, { allowDiskUse => 1 } );

        # query & iterate
            while (my $row = $res->next) {
            # it is 'p', from Data::Printer!
            p $row;
        }
```

It randomly keeps failing with below error :--

```
MongoDB::NetworkTimeout: Timed out while waiting for socket to become ready for reading
```

Now, from what I read we need to change socketTimeoutMS value to something larger. But I am not sure where do I set it ?

Also, maxTimeMS  or maxPoolSize will help in this scenario ? The field @permissibleCars may have around 10K records.

Regards.

Comment: Means what it says. Nothing listening on that socket. Probably because the default socket port for `mongod` is `27017` unless you specifically asked the server to start on a different port. So it looks like your client is trying to connect to the wrong port.

Comment: No, In that case it should fail for everything but what is happening is suppose it is giving the count for ABC , DEF and then it starts failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the connect and socket timeouts via the connection string as follows:

```
MongoDB->connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27012/test_db?connectTimeoutMS=...;socketTimeoutMS=...')
```

The MongoDB Perl driver also allows you to set timeouts via the [connect](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB#connect) method (more details [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::MongoClient#ATTRIBUTES)).